# Jbpm community edition can it be used in production

Tags: jbpm

We are contemplating to use jbpm for workflow
But can we use community edition in production 
Are there any case studies using jbpm community edition in production 
Also does jbpm work only on rhel

Answer (score 0):

If you are building some business-critical application on top of jBPM, I would recommend you to use productized version called [JBoss BPM Suite](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite/). Community final versions usually contain all the features that appear in this product but they do not include all the fixes that go to the final version of the product and you do not receive any bugfix releases (for the given minor release).

When it comes to supported operating systems, in addition to RHEL, jBPM can also run on Windows, Solaris, and AIX.